# Export DynamoDb data to a newly created S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I'm trying to figure out the solutions of how exporting DynamoDB tables to a newly created S3 buckets. The bucket size is around 700TB (700000 GB). I have looked at different solutions which I have added below, but I'm looking for any other solution which can be more efficient, which can export data faster and in a cheaper way.

### First Solution (DynamoDB Export to S3 Feature)

Making use of the feature [DynamoDB data export to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataExport.HowItWorks.html). DynamoDB export to S3 allows you to export both full and incremental data from your DynamoDB table. Exports do not consume any read capacity units (RCUs) and have no impact on table performance and availability.

I tried calculating some rough estimates :
*For a DynamoDB table of size 177.2 megabytes, it exported data to an S3 bucket of size 33.2 megabytes. So for exporting 1 MB of DynamoDB of data ~ it will be take around ~ (33.2 / 177.2) ~= 0.1873MB of S3 storage and for exporting 1TB of DynamoDB data it will take around ~ 187.3 GB.*

### Second Solution (Crawler, Glue Table, AWS Glue Job)

This solution basically involves using Glue crawlers to analyze and catalog the DynamoDB data, Glue tables to define the schema, and Glue jobs to perform the actual export.

**Crawler** → A glue crawler is used to crawl the DynamoDB to identify the schema and populate the metadata in the AWS Glue Data Catalog table.

**Glue Table** → Crawler creates the table with the schema. The Glue table definition includes information about the schema, data types, and other properties of the DynamoDB data.

**Glue Job** → The job will read data from the DynamoDB table, apply any specified transformations, and write the results to the specified S3 bucket. It reads the data from the catalog which has the database and glue table created. We end up specifying the source (DynamoDB) and destination (S3) connections within the Glue job. We can run it on-demand or schedule it to run at specified intervals.

### Third Solution (AWS Glue DynamoDB export connector)

The new  AWS Glue DynamoDB export connector. It’s built on top of the [DynamoDB table export feature](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/accelerate-amazon-dynamodb-data-access-in-aws-glue-jobs-using-the-new-aws-glue-dynamodb-elt-connector/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20new,this%20to%20ddb%20or%20s3). The export feature uses the DynamoDB backup/export functionality (so it doesn't do a scan on the source table). In other words, it performs the Export to S3 (described above) under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple here:

1. If you don't need to filter/transform the data, use the Export to S3 feature, it handles the entire export and even compresses the data to reduce S3 costs.
2. If you require transformations, use AWS Glue. Don't use the export to S3 o Glue, as you don't want to write to S3 twice.

Comment: Is there any way can I calculate how much time would it take to export 700TB of data from dynamoDB to S3 if I end up using first solution?

Comment: Afraid not, there are too many factors at play, data skewness, partition count etc... but it's highly parallelized. You should have access to an account SA?